# Laravel 5 integrate with SAML 2 with existing IDP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, saml, saml-2.0

I'm on Laravel 5, I'm trying to integrate SAML 2.0 with it. 
I've found this package = https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

I tried follow their steps. Under their **Configuration Section**, they said:

> you need to configure your sp and IDP (remote server).

But in my case is a litte different, I work with other ITs that handle the existing iDP. They provided me their metadata end-point.

In that case, do I still need to configure my own iDP/SP?

If so, how can I do that in Laravel?

Answer (score 3):

The package you mentioned, as its documentation says:

> A Laravel package for Saml2 integration as a SP (service provider)
>   based on OneLogin toolkit

So you use it to turn your lavarel app in a SP and connect it with an IdP.
That why you need in the settings IdP and SP data.

[Here](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/blob/master/src/config/saml2_settings.php) you can find the file with the settings of the lavarel package.

At the end, those settings fill the Onelogin's PHP settings, documented [here](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml#settings)